# How to add a new AD Group into a group that is in an OU that is in another OU in a SPD 2010 workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, active-directory

Using SPD 2010 Workflow ("Create Group in Active Directory Properties")
I am trying to add a new group into an OU , that is in another OU.
Like this: OU=Gamma, OU=Beta, OU=Alpha, DC=greek, DC=com

The trouble is I am trying to add a new group into "Gamma" which is a group and not an OU.
Am I using the correct syntax above because I am getting an error?

```
Error Occurred
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072030): There is no such object on the server. 

   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) 
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() 
   at System.Dire
```